# How while loop execute in the shell script for the FALSE condition?

Tags: shell-script

I tried it with some example but it is not clear to me.

FIRST EXAMPLE

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
    echo "$i"
    i=`echo "$i + 1" | bc`
done
```

output   ===> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

now when i executed while  "while [ true ] "  it gives the output as infinite loop  //I agree//
but when i executed while  "while [ false ] "  again it gives the output as  infinite loop. /I dont agree/

Can you please explain the second while loop? and how it is working actually?

```
while [ false ]    #give the infinite loop
while [ true ]     #give the infinite loop
while [ 0 ]        #give the infinite loop
while [ 1 ]        #give the infinite loop
while [ `ls` ]
while [ `echo 1` ] #give the infinite loop
while((0))         #loop not execute
while((1))         #give the infinite loop
```

Comment: First, do you know the difference between [] and (()) ? [] is a test operator. (()) arithmetic evaluator.

Comment: what is return statement of "[ $i -lt 10 ]" if i=5 @Vikyboss

Comment: When you evaluate a expression inside test operator [], it should return an exit code of 0 for the expression evaluating to true and non-zero if false. [ $i -lt 10 ] is saying i(5) is less than 10, so it returns an exit code of 0.

Comment: I would suggest you to read man page of 'test' and 'bash'.

Comment: if we write  the script like
while 1 do echo "hello" done
while 0 do echo "hello" done

Comment: I would suggest you to read `help if` and `help while`. `[ blah blah ]` is just a command. Ah, read `help [` and `help '(('` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `while [ false ]` the `false` is neither a command nor a boolean value. The `while` expects a command but `[ ... ]` with no operators just checks for any non-empty string. Thus `[ false ]` is true. It is in this sense the same as `[ faaaalseeee ]`.

What you meant is:

```
while true; do ...

while false; do ...
```

Comment: then how it execute...??
like c language "while(0)" --> it will never execute

Comment: @Tiger I don't understand the question.

Comment: then what about this statement   " echo `[ $i -lt 10 ]`    "

Comment: simply i want when while loop is execute    and what is return statement of "[ $i -lt 10 ]"   if i=5

Comment: @Tiger Your first example does show that the exit code of `[ 5 -lt 10 ]` is zero (i.e. true). `echo [ $i -lt 10 ]` is just an `echo` statement, the `[ $i -lt 10 ]` part has no meaning other than a string (or rather: several strings). `echo` always exists with zero no matter what the output string is.

Comment: @Tiger: Does this help? `[ 5 -lt 10 ]; echo $?` and `[ 35 -lt 10 ]; echo $?`

Comment: but i think echo $? return 0 (if last command execute successfully) or non-zero then last command is not execute successful then while loop depends on exit status of command  in squire bracket ?

Comment: thnakq so much now i m understand :) and clear my all doubt

Comment: Note: the command `:` has properties equivalent to `true` (as in code it reads `while :` resembling python or lua)